# Random image in html web

Tags: html, image, src

I have a script which generates a gif with this order

```
DATE=$(date +"%s")
cp /var/www/on.gif /var/www/daemonstate$DATE.gif
```

Each time I execute, the filename changes.
My problem is, when I try to put the gif file in my html web with

```
<img src="http://erbicam.no-ip.biz/daemon + * + .gif">
```

the file does not appear, I know this is not the right syntax but I cannot find the right ones.

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          alarma
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Put a short description of the service here
# Description:       Put a long description of the service here
### END INIT INFO

# Change the next 3 lines to suit where you install your script and what you     want to call it
DIR=/home/pi
DAEMON=$DIR/alarma.py
DAEMON_NAME=alarma

# Add any command line options for your daemon here
DAEMON_OPTS=""

# This next line determines what user the script runs as.
# Root generally not recommended but necessary if you are using the Raspberry Pi     GPIO from Python.
DAEMON_USER=root

DATE=$(date +"%s")

# The process ID of the script when it runs is stored here:
PIDFILE=/var/run/$DAEMON_NAME.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start () {
    log_daemon_msg "Starting system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    rm -f /var/www/daemon*
    cp /var/www/on.gif /var/www/daemonstate$DATE.gif
    log_end_msg $?
}
do_stop () {
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping system $DAEMON_NAME daemon"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PIDFILE --retry 10
    rm -f /var/www/daemon*
    cp /var/www/off.gif /var/www/daemonstate$DATE.gif

    log_end_msg $?
}

case "$1" in

    start|stop)
        do_${1}
        ;;

    restart|reload|force-reload)
        do_stop
        do_start
        ;;

    status)
        status_of_proc "$DAEMON_NAME" "$DAEMON" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;


    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$DAEMON_NAME {start|stop|restart|status}"
        exit 1
        ;;

esac
exit 0
```

Comment: What do you hope will happen with this code?   If you want to load an image into a web page, you need to know the file name, you can't use a wildcard.  You could, for example, write a script that sends the most recent image, and put the name of your script in the arc attribute

Comment: how are you executing the script?

Comment: please tag appropriately, i don't think it's just simple html

Comment: Why even change the name?

Comment: Is not possible to load the image with something like "load the image that starts with daemonstate..."?

Comment: Because the image is catched and don´t refresh

Comment: You could create a symlink from `/var/www/daemonstate$DATE.gif` to a file of your choice and use this in your HTML code: `ln -s /var/www/daemonstate$DATE.gif /var/www/mystatus.gif` (Untested!)

Comment: ... or just `cp` the file to another filename ...

Comment: The cp in already in the daemon. and give me a file like daemonstate83663646.gif

Comment: If your sole reason for changing the name of the file is to bust the cache, then just append a query string to the name in the HTML like `....gif?8647984`

Comment: Yes, this in the sole reason. This ....gif?8647984 creates a random archive each time? What means the question mark?